# How to bring up tooltip on button click

Tags: macos, cocoa, tooltip, nsbutton

I've got a warning/ caution icon that appears when the user inputs something that might not be quite correct. The explanation of what might be wrong appears as a tooltip when the user hovers over the icon.

I want the tooltip to also appear when the user **clicks** on the icon, so I made it into a NSButton, but I can't find any way to force the display of the tooltip.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 4):

You can use context-sensitive help to instantly show the tooltip:

```
NSHelpManager *helpManager = [NSHelpManager sharedHelpManager];
[helpManager setContextHelp:[[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[view toolTip]] autorelease] forObject:view];
[helpManager showContextHelpForObject:view locationHint:[NSEvent mouseLocation]];
[helpManager removeContextHelpForObject:view];
```

Comment: This doesn't style the tooltip in the expected, usual tooltip, manner.